# Kendo Mobile UI Border

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, kendo-ui

I am new to kendo UI and hence facing difficulty in fixing this issue . I have a Kendo Code which has a tab strip and its contents .The Problem is a red border is applied for the entire content> I tried to remove it using this styling

```
 <style>
div.k-tabstrip {
    background: none transparent;
    border-width: 0;
}
div.k-tabstrip .k-tabstrip-items {
    padding: 0;
}
div.k-tabstrip .k-content {
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Apply like below.

```
div.k-tabstrip>.k-content
{
 border-width:0 !important;
}
```